# Laptop Froze, Did a Hard Reboot and Lost Networking

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, reboot, crash

Earlier I left my laptop unattended for a few moments and when I returned to it, Ubuntu had evidently frozen. This has never happened before. I did a hard reboot (held down power button) and restarted. When I logged back in I noticed my WiFi network wasn't picked up automatically. Now it seems I've lost all ability to connect to my network, either wirelessly or wired. I can see recent networks I've join but there is no join button, only Add / Edit / Delete.

Note: I did run some update scripts before I walked away from the computer.

After doing some Googling, I ran

`sudo iwconfig` and that gave me

```
eth0    no wireless extensions.
lo      no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking this as answered. I left the laptop alone for a few hours, booted it up, and it picked up my WiFi automatically. Very strange. Maybe the wireless card overheated or something?

Answer (score 0):

(Don't have comment privileges, so I am writing in the answer section ...)

Could you specify what "update scripts" you ran? Was it just "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade" as root? Or was it something else?

Your iwconfig output does not show a WLAN interface! Eth0 should be the ethernet interface. LO0 is the loopback interface. You should have wlan0, assuming you had wlan0 earlier.

Only things I can think of:
1. Your WLAN card's drivers got messed up during the update.
2. Your WLAN card died.
3. Somebody's messing with you. :)

Plz check all those possibilities and let us know.

Comment: Yes those are the updates I ran. How can I check my WLAN's drivers and how do I check if it died?

Comment: could you publish the output of lspci and lsusb commands?

Comment: Marking this as answered. I left the laptop alone for a few hours, booted it up, and it picked up my WiFi automatically. Very strange. Maybe the wireless card overheated or something?